# Microsoft PowerApps calling Power Automate flow Errors out "BadGateway"

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, microsoft365

I have a PowerApps application that calls an instant flow. It worked fine in testing -- it works fine for weeks. Then all of a sudden I get an error:

`InstantWorkflow.Run failed: {"error":{"code": 502, "source": "msmanaged-na.azure-apim.net", "clientRequestId": "[guid]", "message": "BadGateway", "innerError": {"error": {"code": "noResponse", "message": "The server did not receive a response from an upstream server. Request tracking id '[34 letters and numbers]'."}}}}`

The solution to *fix* the problem has always been to go back in, copy the code from the event that's executing the run method of the instant flow, click "power automate" -> reselect the flow I'm trying to run, then paste my code overwriting what PowerApps put in there.

To me, this is an unacceptable solution since my end users see an error and I have to go in and do a fix.

Why does this happen? Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: Its difficult to say what the potential problem is and what a fix would be without seeing which Action is failing and looking for patterns in the Run History, etc. These "gremlins" happy with any low-code platform because *so much* of the infrastructure is abstracted away from you.

Comment: The good news is, someone has likely already solved the problem, you just have to look in the right place. There are [89 "Bad Gateway" results in the PowerApps Forums](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/forums/searchpage/tab/message?advanced=false&allow_punctuation=false&filter=location&location=category:PowerApps1&q=%22Bad%20Gateway%22) and [498 in the Power Automate Forums](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/forums/searchpage/tab/message?advanced=false&allow_punctuation=false&filter=location&location=category:MPACommunity&q=bad%20gateway). When you find out, post here too!

Comment: @SeaDude, No "action" is failing, there's no failures in run history. It's like it takes one glance at the instant workflow and fails without trying to run it, throwing this error for my powerapps user

Comment: @SeaDude, if crawling the powerapps forums got me an answer I wouldn't have posted this question here. I spent weeks looking there and there's absolutely no satisfaction there.

Comment: Cool. So did you figure out what the issue was?

Comment: Nope, still ongoing

Answer (score 0):

Kicked myself after troubleshooting this for a few days because its so basic....make sure attachments are enabled on the list!!